# Is it possible to remove the bounty on this question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

A few days ago I posted a small bounty on the this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87290/basis-of-primitive-nth-roots-in-a-cyclotomic-extension) about a basis for cyclotomic extensions.

KCd left a comment asking that the bounty be removed. I'm perfectly happy to have the bounty removed 2 days early if it's unnecessary in order to clear up the featured page. If not, I'll just not award it.

If possible, could the moderators please delete the offered bounty? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The moderator ability to refund bounties is meant for exceptional circumstances. The most common case in which it is used that I know of is when a problematic question manages to survive long enough to get a bounty. The bounty prevents the question from being closed, so if the moderators decide that the question really should have been closed, they can refund the bounty so that they can close it.

Regularly removing bounties would mean those bounties were "free", the questions get the additional exposure without the user paying for the bounty. I don't think it's a good idea to go down this path, removing bounties should be reserved for exceptional circumstances.

Comment: I definitely agree with this philosophy. Just to be clear though, I wasn't asking for a refund, but a simple annihilation.

Comment: @yunone moderators can't delete bounties, they can only refund them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the problem. What happened, actually? If KCd answered your question, why not award the bounty to him?

Comment: I don't get it either, but that's what Keith wanted. I'll see if he is willing to drop by and say why.

Comment: @Grigory I would award it, but KCd specifically asked that the bounty be removed, so I'm trying to respect that request and get the bounty removed.

Comment: Oh. Reading the comment I thought that KCd just don't want the question to remain featured. Hope, he'll clarify.

Comment: If someone for some reason doesn't want the rep points from the bounty, then he can easily get rid of them by putting a bounty with the same number of points on some other interesting question. (I guess there are enough unanswered interesting questions around - of course it is subjective what you consider interesting.)

Comment: I just wasn't interested in the extra points for answering  question beyond whatever might normally arise, but since I don't plan to post questions here often Martin's suggestion isn't too feasible. And I didn't take Fabian's point into account ("free" bounties) at the time I posted that I didn't want it, so in retrospect I will take the bounty -- however that is awarded -- and we can forget the whole matter.